# image magick php, install

Tags: php

does image magick come bundled with php? if so how do i enable it, if not where and what do i have to do to integrate it.

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default its not bundled with php, you need to install an extension.

Maybe this could help you: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

BTW just search imagick, php and the OS and you will find how to install.